# How does Command Z work through computer commands?

Tags: algorithms

How does Command Z work through computer commands? What is the step by step computer commands that complete the process?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undo#Undo_implementation

Answer (score 1):

You should really try to implement this yourself, and then it will become quite obvious.

You define a [*stack*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) where you put all the *operations* that the user performs.  Here are some examples:

- Close window
- Move file from one directory to another
- Create file
- Move icon on Desktop from $(x_1,y_1)$ to $(x_2, y_2)$
- Type a character
- Delete a character
- Copy to clipboard

All of these operations have reasonable "inverse" operations.:

- Close window → Reopen window
- Move file from A to B → Move it back to A
- Create file X → Delete file X
- Move icon from pos1 to pos2 → Move it back to pos1
- Type a character → Delete the previous typed character, etc.

When the stack contains "reversable" operations, the undo command simply *pops* the last operation off the stack and performs its inverse operation.

Some operations are not reversable, though, such as posting on the Internet, and permanently deleting a file.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches:

1. For each action, implement a reverse action that exactly undoes its effects.
2. Before each action, save the current state and implement a general mechanism to support reverting to a previous state. So basically you keep a FIFO stack of states - or if you also have Redo, a list of states with a pointer to the current state; Undo and Redo move the pointer back and forth.

Approach 1 is infeasible in most cases. It requires actions to be reversible in the first place. So you probably want to go with approach two.

There may be multiple levels of application state. Undo/redo is supposed to apply to the application's subject matter (the work being done), not to the full application state.

A diagram editor I once worked on essentially had four levels of application state that I think most applications have:

1. Persisted work. In my case: what is saved to file; a diagram with some additional information. The application kept an in-memory object model for that and methods to write and read it to/from file. Undo only worked up to the last saved version. So after each save, the undo stack would be emptied.
2. Some extra info saved for undoing purposes. In my case, the editor allow the user to select shapes within the diagram; operations then applied to that selection, and undoing an operation would restore that selection, but it was not being saved to file.
3. Temporary intermediate states that only exist during multi-step operations. For instance, in a diagram editor, while the user is drawing, or moving shapes around, the diagram will pass through intermediate states that are not saved for undoing purposes.
4. Other aspects of the application state that aren't considered part of the subject matter being worked on. For instance, this diagram editor had several modes it could be in besides editing mode. Mode switches were not part of the undo/redo mechanism.  It also had a range of configurable user preferences, e.g. for how to display the diagrams and whether to automatically apply certain operations to the diagram after an editing operation. Those preferences are a separate piece of state, saved separately, and undo/redo does not affect them.

In terms of [Model-View-Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller):

1. The *model* is the subject matter being operated on; it is what is persisted to file, or to some other persistent medium.
2. The *controller* is what is used to modify the model, e.g. the diagram editor in my case; it defines operations on the model; it may adorn the model with some additional state that operations depend on (in my case, the current set of selected shapes); undo/redo is an operation within the controller, and operates on that adorned model.
3. The *view* defines what the user is currently seeing and is probably stateful, too, but state specific to the view is not subject to undo/redo.